# DC bar chart Y axis with integer scale (not multiplicated)

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I want to create a dynamic bar chart with no of occurences on Y axis. Therefore, I need to make sure that only integer values are shown and this can be done with proper format:

```
chart.yAxis().tickFormat(d3.format('f'));
```

Right now I have only integer numbers but I have for example 1 displayed 3 times:

[image: example]

Is there any option to automatically display it in a nice way (i.e. to minimize number of ticks for charts with shorter range)?

Comment: Are you looking for [d3.axis.ticks](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Axes.md#ticks)?

Comment: yes, I have finally got it. Had to add condition based on max Y value. Thx for a tip

Answer (score 0):

```
chart.yAxis().tickFormat(d3.format("d"));
```

will work.

Comment: That will just duplicate the numbers if the values are 1 and 1.5 for example

Answer (score 0):

When you append the yAxis, define the ticks the same number as the max value of your y

```
svg.append("g").call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(maxY));
```

Or in your example that would be

```
chart.yAxis().ticks(maxY);
```

Or instead of defining the ticks, you could also define the exact tickValues which you can calculate from your values, this way you have the highest control.